# Using a subquery inside of a where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue with my stored procedure.

The general idea is to be able to select a 4 parameters (which can be selected or not) and return the correct results.  Because I really cant get this to work with 2 parameters (Campus ID is mandatory) I haven't bothered to do the others.

The issue lies in my where clause

```
       WHERE ac.AC_Campus_ID = @CampusID AND
          (

                ac.AC_College_ID IN (CASE @CollegeID
                WHEN 0 THEN (select distinct AC_College_ID from AC_Academic_Choice)
                ELSE @CollegeID
                END))
```

This is an example.  I select a campus id of 1 and I selected a college id of 1.  The query will return the results for those 2 parameters.

When I select a campus id of 1 and a college id of 0.. I get "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

When I do the second input I want all the results of every college id in the system.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to rewrite it to get your desired results:

```
...
WHERE ac.AC_College_ID IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT AC_College_ID 
  FROM AC_Academic_Choice
  WHERE AC_College_ID = 
    CASE @CollegeID
      WHEN 0
      THEN AC_College_ID 
      ELSE @CollegeID 
    END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   WHERE ac.AC_Campus_ID = @CampusID AND
      (SELECT 1 WHERE ac.AC_College_ID IN 
            (CASE @CollegeID
            WHEN 0 THEN (select distinct AC_College_ID from AC_Academic_Choice)
            ELSE @CollegeID
            END
            )
      )
```

Comment: sgeddes's answer is better.